# Prewritten PHP Script Showing Errors - Cannot Figure Out Why The Error Exists

Tags: php, variables, thumbnails

I'm using a pre-written script found at [1st Web Magazine - Generate Thumbnail On The Fly](http://1stwebmagazine.com/generate-thumbnail-on-the-fly-with-php).

I copied the script over to my server, but it's giving me the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$ratio_orig' (T_VARIABLE) in /storage/emulated/legacy/www/jollyroger/jollyroger/img/gallery_temp/thumbnail.php on line 23`

I've went through the code and I cannot spot any actual errors. Everything seems to be in order.

Could someone take a look at this code and tell me if I am overlooking something? From what I can gather it seems that something in the `list()` function is throwing off the variables.

This is the code actually in my file:

```
<?php
// thumb width
$square = 150;
$large = 200;
$small = 100;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// square
if( isset($_GET["img"]) &&  ( $_GET["type"] == "square" || $_GET["type"] == "" ) ){
// thumb size
$thumb_width = $square;
$thumb_height = $square; 
// align
$align = $_GET["align"];
// image source
$imgSrc = $_GET["img"];
$imgExt = substr($imgSrc,-3);
// image extension
if($imgExt == "jpg"){ $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc); }
if($imgExt == "gif"){ $myImage = imagecreatefromgif($imgSrc); }
if($imgExt == "png"){ $myImage = imagecreatefrompng($imgSrc); }
// getting the image dimensions  
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imgSrc);   
 // ratio
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
// landscape or portrait?
if ($thumb_width/$thumb_height > $ratio_orig) {
$new_height = $thumb_width/$ratio_orig;
$new_width = $thumb_width;
} else {
$new_width = $thumb_height*$ratio_orig;
$new_height = $thumb_height;
}
// middle
$x_mid = $new_width/2;
$y_mid = $new_height/2;
// create new image
$process = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height)); 
imagecopyresampled($process, $myImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height); 
// alignment
if($align == ""){
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, ($x_mid-($thumb_width/2)), ($y_mid-($thumb_height/2)), $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
}
if($align == "top"){
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, ($x_mid-($thumb_width/2)), 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
}
if($align == "bottom"){
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, ($x_mid-($thumb_width/2)), ($new_height-$thumb_height), $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
}
if($align == "left"){
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, 0, ($y_mid-($thumb_height/2)), $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
}
if($align == "right"){
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, ($new_width-$thumb_width), ($y_mid-($thumb_height/2)), $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
}
imagedestroy($process);
imagedestroy($myImage); 
if($imgExt == "jpg"){ imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100); }
if($imgExt == "gif"){ imagegif($thumb); }
if($imgExt == "png"){ imagepng($thumb, null, 9); }
 }
// normal
if(isset($_GET["img"]) && ($_GET["type"] == "large" || $_GET["type"] == "small" ) ){
if( $_GET["type"] == "large" ){ $thumb_width = $large; }
if( $_GET["type"] == "small" ){ $thumb_width = $small; }
// image source
$imgSrc = $_GET["img"];
$imgExt = substr($imgSrc,-3);
// image extension
if($imgExt == "jpg"){ $myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc); }
if($imgExt == "gif"){ $myImage = imagecreatefromgif($imgSrc); }
if($imgExt == "png"){ $myImage = imagecreatefrompng($imgSrc); }
//getting the image dimensions  
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imgSrc);   
// ratio
$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;
$thumb_height = $thumb_width/$ratio_orig;
// new dimensions
$new_width = $thumb_width;
$new_height = $thumb_height;
// middle
$x_mid = $new_width/2;
$y_mid = $new_height/2;
// create new image
$process = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_width), round($new_height));
imagecopyresampled($process, $myImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height); 
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $process, 0, 0, ($x_mid-($thumb_width/2)), ($y_mid-($thumb_height/2)), $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $thumb_width, $thumb_height);
if($imgExt == "jpg"){ imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100); }
if($imgExt == "gif"){ imagegif($thumb); }
if($imgExt == "png"){ imagepng($thumb, null, 9); }
}
?>
```

Even this line in my editor is highlighted red which indicates an error, but since the variable is triggering a php error this one has not shown up in any logs yet. Looking over this line I cannot spot anything wrong at all.

`if(isset($_GET["img"]) && ($_GET["type"] == "large" || $_GET["type"] == "small" ) ){`

I copied the code direct from the website so I'm at a loss as to why it is not working. As I said I've looked it over and everything seems to be in order, so I'm at a complete loss.

Also this script is in the same directory as my image files. My test url looks like so: `http://localhost:8080/jollyroger/jollyroger/img/gallery_temp/thumbnail.php?img=1959523_1501438810115481_7515978806557307096_n.jpg`

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact same script that you posted here? I would almost bet that you accidentally deleted the semicolon on the code line before, at the end of `list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imgSrc);   
`

Comment: The code I listed here is copied from my code editor. If it's missing in my code it's missing here too. That's why I provided a link to the original. I can't spot any differences or reasons for the error.

Comment: Hmh, really strange. As there are no empty lines in your post here but in the source you linked are several in the code, I suspect you did anything with it (at least remove the line breaks). Therefore, can you try the following: Copy & Paste the script again from the page you linked, and just do not change anything. Do you get the same error then?

Comment: No change. Same errors.

Comment: try to change your `list()` into 4 variable. Something like: `list($width_orig, $height_orig, $type_orig, $attribut)`

Comment: Still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something.

you have the following line:

```
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($imgSrc);
```

which seems really weird to me. You are equalling a function to a function which might cause the error on the next line.

If that's not the problem then either you forgot a `;` or you tried to access the variable before you set its value somewhere.

Comment: Maybe changing it to something like `$getimagesize = getimagesize($imgSrc); list($width_orig, $height_orig) - $getimagesize;`?

Comment: I disagree. This is how list() actually works. See the [PHP manual for list()](http://php.net/list). I agree it is weird, but well ... things are often weird in PHP :)

Comment: in that case scrap my first solution :p